# Constructor in an Anonymous AsyncTask like this "new AsyncTask<Exercise,Void,Void>()"?

Tags: java, android, constructor, android-asynctask, anonymous-function

It is really a pain in the ass for me putting every work in AsyncTask Classes, that are somewhere in my Code, but the Code does not execute, where I expect him to execute.

I used to use the `new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){}` Function to have the Code where I expect him and this works fine for every.

If I want to use the AsyncTask with Variables from my parent Class it warns me of possible memory leaks, of course.

Is there a way to have a constructor in this anonymous AsyncTask? I think no, but it would be really nice if there is a way to keep the code in place, but passing variables into the Async Task.

Maybe something like this:

```
        AsyncTask<Exercise, Void, Void> insert = new AsyncTask <Exercise, Void, Void>(){
            private Exercise mExercise;
            
            public AsyncTask(Exercise exercise){
                mExercise = exercise;
            }
            
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Exercise... exercises) {
                mExerciseDAO.insertExercise(exercises[0]);
                return null;
            }

        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to pass your Exercise parameter to an anonymous AsyncTask:

```
new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){

    Exercise mExercise;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        // Your code ...
        mExerciseDAO.insertExercise(this.mExercise);
        return null;
    }

    public AsyncTask setExercise (Exercise exercise){
        this.mExercise = exercise;
        return this;
    }

}.setExercise(exercise).execute();
```